# Make image slider from url in android studio

Tags: java, android

I'm beginner in android, i have image slider but image inside in source project, how can get image from url and show in image slider.

This is my adapter :

```
public class adapter_image_slider extends PagerAdapter {

Context mContext;

public adapter_image_slider(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return sliderImagesId.length;
}

private int[] sliderImagesId = new int[]{
        R.drawable.imghome1, R.drawable.imghome2, R.drawable.imghome3,
};

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View v, Object obj) {
    return v == ((ImageView) obj);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int i) {
    ImageView mImageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    mImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    mImageView.setImageResource(sliderImagesId[i]);
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(mImageView, 0);
    return mImageView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int i, Object obj) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) obj);
}

}
```

and this my main_activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_slider);

    ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPageAndroid);
    adapter_image_slider adapterView = new adapter_image_slider(this);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(adapterView);
}
```

Somebody please help...

Comment: use [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) for loading images from Url.

Comment: Use best library for both URL image and resource 
https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider

Comment: oh thanks for response, i will try it

Answer (score 0):

You can use Glide or Picasso.
https://github.com/bumptech/glide
Glide is a fast and efficient open source media management and image loading framework for Android that wraps media decoding, memory and disk caching, and resource pooling into a simple and easy to use interface.
https://github.com/square/picasso
Picasso: A powerful image downloading and caching library for Android

Comment: do you have a link of tutorial glide for image slider..?

Comment: You can use https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider if you want it specifically for Image sliding.

Answer (score -2):

you can create constructor with ArrayList ids ....

```
public class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

ArrayList<Integer> imageIds;

public ImagePagerAdapter(ArrayList<Integer> imageIds) {
    this.imageIds = imageIds;
}
```

and send ids and use it.

```
ArrayList<Integer> imageIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i = 1 ; i < 15 ; i++) {
        int id = getApplicationContext.getResources().getIdentifier("image" + i,"drawable" ,getApplicationContext.getPackageName() );
        imageIds.add(id);
    }
```

But it does not use the URL. just reads from storage